# Does Palpatine have 3-4 lightsabers available to him?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, the-clone-wars, darth-sidious

I just saw the episode of Star Wars: The Clone Wars, "[The Lawless](http://clonewars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lawless)", and

> I saw Palpatine use 2 lightsabers to combat Maul and Savage.

One looks very similar to the one he used against Mace Windu in *Revenge of the Sith*. However, that one was in the statue in Palpatine's office and before Mace and his Jedi team confronted him, Palpatine telekinetically activated it and then retrieved it for the first time in over a decade. He later lost it and then used a back-up against Yoda. So does Palpatine have 3 or 4 lightsabers or is this another wonderful continuity error from *The Clone Wars*?

Comment: Damn, you've just spoiled me... Can you please hide the spoilers..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pure speculation, since at first glance it does seem to be a continuity error, but just the fact that he was shown to have two near identical lightsabers in E3 would make me think that he had quite an armory, also since Sith lightsabers used synthetic crystals (and they were mass produced for Marek clones post-republic) it does not seem far fetched that he either made or acquired many of them.

Also, Sith (and especially Palpatine) did not get as attached to their weapon as Jedi did, regarding them as only tools, or as in Palpatine's case, decoration. I think this would strengthen the case for him just having an armory lying around.

Comment: Agreed. Its just annoying

Comment: Personally, I envision him having a wall that opens similar to Agent K from Men in Black. Just a huge walk-in closet full of lightsabers and blasters. But that's just me.

Answer (score 2):

The canon explanation is that Palpatine has two lightsabers. He uses them against Savage and Maul, and later uses one while fighting Mace Windu. That one falls out the window when it gets destroyed during the battle. After that, he only uses one.